# Reading in user input with space using scanf in a while loop?

Tags: c, string, file, io, scanf

I'm working on some code in which I am trying to read in the following commands, which will lead to certain functions in my program being called:

```
PRINT
INSERT 0,Folders,Folders for storing related papers,25
PRINT
QUIT
```

I have been trying different ways to read in this input, which comes from `./inventory test02/inventory02-actual.txt < test02/input02.txt > test02/actual02.txt`, in which these commands shown above are in the file input-02.txt.

I've primarily been working with `scanf`, but have tried `fgets`, but I have had the most success to what I desire with `scanf`. I originally tried `scanf("%s", command)` and in this case, scanf does not take in whitespace so the program terminates.

```
//Keep re-prompting user for commands until you reach EOF{
  while ((scanf("%[0-9a-zA-Z, ]s", command) == 1)) {  
    printf("====================\nCommand? ");
    printf("%s\n", command);      
    if (strcmp(command, "PRINT") == 0) {     
      print(list);    
    } else if (strcmp(substring(command, START, INSERT_END), "INSERT") == 0) {    
      //Get the substring - this is the input after "INSERT"
      char string[MAX_LEN_COMMAND];
      strcpy(string, substring(command, OFFSET, strlen(command)));                     
      insert(string, list);   
    } else if (strcmp(command, "PRINTREVERSE") == 0) {
      printReverse(list);
    } else {
      printf("Invalid command passed.\n"); 
      exit(EXIT_BAD_INPUT);
    }
  }
```

Currently, when I run my code, only the first command, "PRINT" is read in. It seems like I cannot read the next line of input from input-02.txt. Is there a way I can read in these commands properly? In addition, after my program reads in "INSERT", it then reads in "0,Folders,Folders for storing related papers,25" as a command, which it should not. It should go directly to the next command, which is "PRINT". I have tried using a continue statement after calling the `insert` method, but that did not work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: Updating code with fgets.

Instead of posting all my functions that I called to above, I think passing a `printf` to show us what the command is might be simple enough for a reproducible example!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OFFSET 7
#define START 0
#define INSERT_END 5

static const char *substring(char command[], int start, int end);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  //Get user input for commands    
  char command[500];

  //Keep re-prompting user for commands until you reach EOF{
  while (fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin) != NULL) {  
    printf("====================\nCommand? ");
    printf("%s\n", command);      
    if (strcmp(command, "PRINT") == 0) {     
      printf("%s", command);    
    } else if (strcmp(substring(command, START, INSERT_END), "INSERT") == 0) {    
      printf("%s", command);   
    } else if (strcmp(command, "PRINTREVERSE") == 0) {
      printf("%s", command);
    } else {
      printf("Invalid command passed.\n"); 
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

static const char *substring(char command[], int start, int end) 
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char *sub;
  sub = (char *)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
  for (i = start, j = 0; i <= end; i++, j++) {
    sub[j] += command[i];
  }
  sub[j] = '\0';
  return sub;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
====================
Command? PRINT

Invalid command passed.
```

Comment: Suggestion: I know you said you had problems with it, but: definitely go with `fgets`. It will be next to impossible to do what you're trying to do here with `scanf`.

Comment: Hi @SteveSummit, is there a good way to implement fgets? For instance, I used `fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin)`, and was unable to even read the first command.

Comment: Regarding `fgets`, if `command` is a `char*` and not a `char[N]`, then yeah, that's not going to work, and since we can't see what you did and the context you did it in... yeah. Update your question with a [mcve] of your `fgets` that failed. It should be reproducible with a the include stack, a single function, a `main`, and maybe a half-dozen lines of code in each. Anything more than that is overkill and/or unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @WhozCraig, I've made an update to my question above with some code that could be run locally.

Comment: @PomegranateSociety Thanks. Now all you need is understanding how `fgets` works. It reads the entire *line*. Once you have that, *then* you can `sscanf` the input for specific content. (or parse pure-manual if that's your bidding). And important: `fgets` *retains* the newline entered on the console or read from file, so unless you want that as part of your compare-against data, you need to clear it (usually done with strpbrk and hard-setting a nullchar, or some similar action).

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please explain to me how strpbk would be able to clear the data I'm comparing it against? I thought strpbk is used to find the first matching occurrence of a character, so I'm just a bit confused!

Comment: The character you're clearing is the last one, (the newline). You can also just check the last char, and if its a newline (it may not be; ex: the last 'line' in a file that happens to not end with '\n'), then just set it to `0` (e.g a terminator)..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading a line, you will have better success with `fgets`.

```
char command[101];   

while (fgets(command, 100, stdin))
{
// rest of the code can be the same
}
```